# run JavaScript function only if Boolean is true

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a functionality of OpenLayers to only work if it has been turned on by the user. I've made html buttons that call functions turning the boolean variable `clickSearch`to true of false. How can I make the function only work with `clicksearch = true`? is it some sort of if statement?

This is the code that runs the function I want to turn on and off:

```
OpenLayers.Control.Click = OpenLayers.Class(OpenLayers.Control, {                
            defaultHandlerOptions: {
                'single': true,
                'double': false,
                'pixelTolerance': 0,
                'stopSingle': false,
                'stopDouble': false
            },

            initialize: function(options) {
                this.handlerOptions = OpenLayers.Util.extend(
                    {}, this.defaultHandlerOptions
                );
                OpenLayers.Control.prototype.initialize.apply(
                    this, arguments
                ); 
                this.handler = new OpenLayers.Handler.Click(
                    this, {
                        'click': this.trigger
                    }, this.handlerOptions
                );
            }, 

            trigger: function(e) {
                var lonlat = map.getLonLatFromPixel(e.xy);
                alert("You clicked near " + lonlat.lat + " N, " +
                                          + lonlat.lon + " E");
            }
            });
```

These functions turn the boolean `clickSearch` on and off

```
var clickSearch= false;

function turnOn(){ clickSearch=true};
function turnOff(){ clickSearch=false};
```

and these buttons call the function to turn `clickSearch` on/off:

```
<button onclick="turnOn()">Turn on click-to-search</button>
<button onclick="turnOff()">Turn off click-to-search</button>
```

Comment: Why not to use if(clickSearch){ } block ?

Comment: Does it needed to make clickSearch initialize??,You can directly call that function at that time.

Comment: You haven't clarified what "disabling" OpenLayers means to you. Should it simply stop `trigger` from running, or should it also perform some kind of cleanup (e.g., remove UI elements)? If stopping `trigger` is enough, then an `if(clickSearch)` block in `trigger` should be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply check your boolean when you want it to have effect.  For example, in your trigger function:

```
trigger: function(e) {
    if (!clickSearch)
        { return; }
    // ...
}
```